# Submitting a partial view form within a modal dialog MVC, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, modal-dialog, partial-views

Here is my code:

```
<td class="tedit">
                    <%= Html.ActionLink(item.Comments, "Comments", new { jobNumber = item.JobNumber, ordNumber = item.OrderNumber }, new { @class = "modalEdit" })%>
 </td>



<div id="resultEdit" title="Edit Comments" style="display: none;">
       <% Html.RenderPartial("AddComments", Model.InnerModel.RoadReportModelProp); %>
</div>



 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //initialize the dialog
            $("#resultEdit").dialog({ modal: true, width: 300, resizable: true, position: 'center', title: 'Add Comments', autoOpen: false,
                buttons: { "Save": function () {
                    var dlg = $(this);
                    dlg.Close();
                   }}
        });
                        });

        $(function () {
            $('.modalEdit').click(function () {
                //load the content from this.href, then turn it into a dialog.
                $('#resultEdit').load(this.href).dialog('open');
                $.unblockUI();
                return false;
            });
        });

      </script>
```

I need to send a POST request to the controller when I click on the SAVE button in the dialog, but I am not able to send a POST.

Please  help.

Comment: I need to save the results into database on POST

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use $.post to save your data. For example

```
$.post(url, data, function(response) {
    // Do something with response
});
```

You will need to collect the data from the dialog.

Regards,

Huske

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to Post, further, can you provide the code for the form you want to post, & also the controller you have created:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //get the form
    var f = $("#idofForm");
    var action = f.attr("action");
    var serializedForm = f.serialize();
    $.post(action, serializedForm, function() {
        alert('we are back');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TH_Dashboard.Models.Reports.RptModel>" %>
   <div id="Comments" style="">
    <% Html.BeginForm(); %>
                            Add Comments:
                            <%=Html.TextArea("tempNotes", new {})%>
                             <input type="submit" name="button" id="SavePartial" value="SavePartial" class="btn" />
                            </div>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>  This is my partial view code

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div> 

        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Post-FormActionName", "Controllername"))
           {
        %>             

             <div class="fieldsColumn">

              <label>Name: *</label>
                <%=Html.TextBoxFor("Name")%>

        </div>

            <div class="fieldsColumn">

              <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save"/>

        </div>


        <%}%>      

</div>
```